# How can I use Facebook login in my app and move to next page/view controller after successfully logIn?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to go to next page/view controller after I log in with Facebook in my iOS app when I press the continue button instead of seeing the "log out button” and the same page. How would I do that?

I tried adding segue here

```
   func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueVC", sender: nil)
    print("sucessfully logged in with FB")


}
```

But it didn’t work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call performSegue in main thread

```
class ViewController:UIViewController {


 func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

   if error != nil {
     print(error)
     return
   }

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueVC", sender: nil)
   }
 }


}
```

Comment: It says *expected declaration* error when I call this on main thread?

Comment: please verify your code in right place. I have edited my answer!

Comment: I had to add ‘self.'in front of ‘performSegue’ but its still not gong to next page and it shows no error

Comment: Check “segueVC” identifier is correct. Also put break point near performSegue.. check whether it is called? If yes override prepareFor segue method and debug segue.destinationViewController to make sure instance is created correctly

Comment: Yep its correct! I linked it from one view control to another as a “show” and named it

Comment: Yep I tried it all, also its being called as when I put the wrong segue name it...crashes.

Comment: Do you have navigation controller

Comment: If don’t you can’t use show you need to select segue as Present modaly

Comment: Nope, I do not, Is it essential?

Comment: For segue style show works only with navigation controllers. Like push. In you don’t have navigation controller you need to select present Modal style while adding segue in storyboard